# Oracle Wallet and Secure External Password Store. Why is it secure?

Tags: oracle

I have read multiple articles on Secure External Password Store and I still can't understand what makes it secure. I have created the wallets myself using orapki to prevent it being copied to other servers etc however essentially what a Secure External Password Store does is keeps the credentials in a format that they are only available to the user you are logging in as I get that. What I don't understand is, if you are taking away the requirement to enter a password at all for a user, how is it secure? Anyone can access your database.

For example, here I make a connection matching the alias in my tnsnames.ora

```
sqlplus /@db11g

DB11G =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = DB11G.WORLD)
    )
  )
```

I require no password, anyone can log in - so why is it secure at all?

Answer (score 0):

Back in the client/server days of the 80s, all the end-users would have their own database user and password (which would be separate from any other username/password they had for other systems in the company because there was non real single-sign on back then).

How most of the database access is done through an application server or other middle-man. And often the 'end user' might be a customer using a web or mobile app that doesn't even work for your company.

So, as far as the database goes, we've lost that 'something you know' authentication method. That middle man application server now has to manage its password. A chunk of the time that means hard-wiring the database user and password into a config file. Sometimes in plain text, or sometimes the app will read a plain text password from a config file and write it back in an eencrypted form (but ultimately a form it can decrypt because it has to be able to get it out to autheniticate itself to the database).

Having the 'wallet' / external password store removes the reliance on the application managing password security. If the application was doing a poor job of it, and leaving an unencrypted password in the config file, then it is a step up from that.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I do understand the concept, locking the authentication means in a secure area. sqlplus /@db11g is for everyone though. Anyone can get in just by typing that... how does it add anything to security if anyone can just type that and they're in.

Comment: @Scouse_Bob - Your app server shouldn't have a sqlplus client on it. The entire purpose of the app server is to run an application accessing the database. If they can log into the app server, then they are in the database. 

The secure external password store is about protecting a free-text password from sitting around in files that can get exfiltrated, copied, backed up, stored in version control etc.

Comment: Hmm. If they are in the app server they are in the database, agreed. However controlling access to the application can be done a number of ways and limited in a number of ways too. Often assigned on a per user basis so you know who is doing what. You can make it secure. This thing "/@db11g"  and I'm in, it doesn't need any authentication. There is no access control. Anyone can get in easily. What am I missing Gary... :-/

Comment: @Scouse_Bob 'Anyone can get in' - NO, only people with access to the server and file, which is basically noone. Your problem is that you aren't comparing the secure external password store to any other mechanism of securing access between app server and database.  This is for securing a DB user that is shared across all application users. If you want everyone to log in to the application with their own database username/password combination, like the old client server days, go ahead. If you never want anyone to access the DB, a gallon of petrol and a match will 'secure' it